# Flex 3 Hiding "764 bytes after decompression" trace statements

Tags: apache-flex, zip, compression

Hey, i'm working on a flex project where we load in a bunch of swf files from a zip archive using fzip. And whenever i'm running in debug mode, I get a whole bunch of trace statements saying like, [SWF] filepath - 251 bytes after decompression

I'm just wondering if anyone knows how to hide these statements in the output window as there are a lot of them as i've got over 200 swf files being loaded in and these statements just create clutter for my other log statements.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way.

My only suggestion would be to use an external logger.  Something like XRay that displays the output in a separate window.

Comment: Thanks, XRay looks pretty neat. Kind of silly that theres no way to disable that trace statement though :(